# Djangocms users don't have permission to add or edit plugins

Tags: django, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I have a website, currently running with Django==1.8.6 and Django-CMS 3.0.x (running through upgrades at the moment).

My users can not edit any of the frontend plugins. At the moment I am sure that this is not only true for my custom made plugins, but for ones that come with Django-CMS as well. As a test I have made a new User with all rights and staff status (no superuser). But also this user can't edit or add plugins.

For my search I have found this: https://github.com/divio/djangocms-text-ckeditor/issues/78

I also tested the solution given there as I am using ckeditor, but I don't have an entry for text, so this:

```
 sqlite3> select * from django_content_type where app_label = 'text';
 id | name | app_label | model 
 ----+------+-----------+-------
 23 | text | text      | text
```

For results to

```
 sqlite3> select * from django_content_type where app_label = 'text';
 sqlite3>
```

I tried to figure out how to debug permission errors. I have also looked through auth_permission, but everything seems to be alright. Is there anyway to debug the permission process in order to find whats preventing my users from using the frontend editing?

**Update**

My current installed packages:

```
Django==1.8.6
Django-Select2==4.3.1
Pillow==3.0.0
South==1.0.2
Unidecode==0.04.18
YURL==0.13
aldryn-apphooks-config==0.2.6
aldryn-boilerplates==0.7.3
aldryn-categories==1.0.1
aldryn-common==1.0.0
aldryn-newsblog==1.0.9
aldryn-people==1.1.2
aldryn-reversion==1.0.1
aldryn-translation-tools==0.2.1
argparse==1.4.0
backport-collections==0.1
cmsplugin-filer==1.0.0
dj-database-url==0.3.0
django-admin-sortable==1.8.4
django-appconf==1.0.1
django-appdata==0.1.4
django-autoslug==1.8.0
django-ckeditor-filebrowser-filer==0.1.1
django-classy-tags==0.6.2
django-cms==3.1.3
django-durationfield==0.5.2
django-easy-select2==1.3
django-filer==1.0.2
django-mptt==0.7.4
django-parler==1.5.1
django-phonenumber-field==0.7.2
django-polymorphic==0.7.2
django-reversion==1.8.7
django-sekizai==0.8.2
django-sortedm2m==1.3.2
django-taggit==0.17.3
django-treebeard==3.0
djangocms-admin-style==1.0.5
djangocms-column==1.5
djangocms-file==0.1
djangocms-flash==0.2.0
djangocms-googlemap==0.3
djangocms-inherit==0.1
djangocms-installer==0.7.9
djangocms-link==1.6.2
djangocms-picture==0.1
djangocms-style==1.5
djangocms-teaser==0.1
djangocms-text-ckeditor==2.7.0
djangocms-video==0.1
easy-thumbnails==2.2.1
gunicorn==19.4.3
html5lib==0.9999999
lxml==3.5.0
phonenumbers==7.1.1
python-dateutil==2.4.2
python-slugify==1.1.4
pytz==2015.7
simplejson==3.8.0
six==1.10.0
tzlocal==1.2
vobject==0.6.6
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Comment: Hello, which django CMS version are you using? (I see 3.0.x but certain things change depending on the minor/patch release).

And does your project have CMS_PERMISSIONS set to True?

Comment: Hi, for now I am at 3.1.3. I have updated to that version because it was the latest without larger changes. The Problem still persist. I have also checked: CMS_PERMISSION = True is set.
I'm also currently working on an update to the latest version. Despite some problems with aldryn-newsblog, I'm nearly done with that. But the problem still persists on this none-productive updated version as well. A hint where to look in the database for these permissions would help a lot. The tables I found seem to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is after some debugging the permissions.py of the cms, that my sitepermissions where not set properly in the database. Resetting thos in the backend solved the problem.